# Unable to send_raw_transaction using Web3.py on Fantom Network

Tags: web3.py, sendrawtransaction, rlp, sendsignedtransaction, fantom

I am currently trying to simply send FTM from one wallet to another on Fantom mainnet, albeit encountering a Value error 'rlp: expected List' as listed below.

```
ftm = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://rpcapi.fantom.network'))

# Check if connected correctly
print(ftm.isConnected())

from_address = ftm.toChecksumAddress(wallet)
value = 0.1
to_address = ftm.toChecksumAddress('to_address')
nonce = ftm.eth.getTransactionCount(from_address)

transaction = {
    'from': from_address,
    'to': to_address,
    'value': ftm.toWei(value, "ether"),
    'gas': 2000000,
    'maxFeePerGas': 2000000000,
    'maxPriorityFeePerGas': 1000000000,
    'nonce': nonce,
    'chainId': 250}  # FTM

signed = ftm.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, pk)
res = ftm.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed.rawTransaction)
txhash = ftm.toHex(ftm.sha3(signed.rawTransaction))
print(txhash)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-361fbe8285cf> in <module>
     24 
     25 signed = ftm.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, pk)
---> 26 res = ftm.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed.rawTransaction)
     27 txhash = ftm.toHex(ftm.sha3(signed.rawTransaction))
     28 print(txhash)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py in send_raw_transaction(self, transaction)
    696 
    697     def send_raw_transaction(self, transaction: Union[HexStr, bytes]) -> HexBytes:
--> 698         return self._send_raw_transaction(transaction)
    699 
    700     def sign_munger(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\web3\module.py in caller(*args, **kwargs)
     55             return LogFilter(eth_module=module, filter_id=err.filter_id)
     56         result_formatters, error_formatters, null_result_formatters = response_formatters
---> 57         result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
     58                                              params,
     59                                              error_formatters,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py in request_blocking(self, method, params, error_formatters, null_result_formatters)
    185         """
    186         response = self._make_request(method, params)
--> 187         return self.formatted_response(response,
    188                                        params,
    189                                        error_formatters,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py in formatted_response(self, response, params, error_formatters, null_result_formatters)
    166         if "error" in response:
    167             apply_error_formatters(error_formatters, response)
--> 168             raise ValueError(response["error"])
    169         elif response['result'] in NULL_RESPONSES:
    170             # null_result_formatters raise either a BlockNotFound

ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'rlp: expected List'}
```

The exact same code works perfect on the Ropstein testnet on Eth (RPC & chain id updated for ropstein), with no luck on Fantom, has anyone been able to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is an issue with EIP-1559, which Ropsten supports but Fantom does not. There's no priority fee in Fantom, only legacy iirc.

So this part of the transactions:

> 'maxFeePerGas': 2000000000,
> 'maxPriorityFeePerGas': 1000000000,

Probably should be replaced with (or which ever other value you want):

> 'gasPrice': ftm.toWei('200', 'gwei'),